# Missing $ inserted on blank line

Tags: math-mode

I get the message "Missing $ inserted" just on a blank line.

After this:

```
1108. a) Avläsning av kruvan $f_{B}(x)$ vid x = 8 ger att $f_{B}(8)$ ≈ 28$.\\
b) \text{Genom att undersöka var kurvan $f_{A}(x)$ skär linjen $T=20$ ser vi att $x \approx {4.3}$ då $f_{A}(x) = 20$}.\\
c) \text{Att lösa ekvationen innebär skärningspunkten mellan kurvorna. Avläsning i diagrammet ger att $x \approx {7,1}$}.
```

And on this line I get the message. Why is there a message on a line without text? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Here: `$f_{B}(8)$ ≈ 28$`. You have an extra `$` (not closed properly anywhere). Should be: `$f_{B}(8) ≈ 28$`, I guess.

Comment: Why are you using `\text`? It's needed only in math formulas (and not frequently).

Comment: Are you spamming this site on purpose? -or what is going on here. You have several similar questions, and not a single minimum working example.